# Random function not compatible with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, random

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = 5
b = 10
c = 20
x = (print(random.randrange(a, b)))
y = (print(random.randrange(b, c)))
projectname = input('What is your project name?: ')
indep = input('What is your independent variable?: ')
dep = input('What is your dependent variable?: ')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel(indep)
plt.ylabel(dep)
plt.title(projectname)
plt.show()
```

Here is the error code:
"ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None"

New to coding

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at these lines

```py
x = (print(random.randrange(a, b)))
y = (print(random.randrange(b, c)))
```

The result of the `print` function is `None`. So the value stored in the `x` and `y` variables is `None` and not the result of `random.randrange`. So when you get to

```py
plt.plot(x, y)
```

your actually saying `plt.plot(None, None)` instead of

```
plt.plot(random.randrange(a, b), random.randrange(b, c))
```

If your wanting to show the user the random values selected you would want something like this

```py
x = random.randrange(a, b)
y = random.randrange(b, c)
print(x)
print(y)
```